# Create custom image with Dockerfile and directly run it locally on Win10

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My humble Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# Dockerfile.Ubuntu
FROM ubuntu:latest as builder
RUN ["touch", "test"]
```

when building the new image with

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.Ubuntu -t "Dummy:1.0" .
```

and issuing `docker images` the newly created images is listed

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
Dummy               11.2                3bffa7d3048d        27 minutes ago      64.2MB
```

but now, when starting the image with the name `docker run -it Dummy bash` i receive this error:

```
Unable to find image 'Dummy:latest' locally C:\PATH....exe: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for Dummy, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```

Using the image id works: `docker run -it 3bffa7d3048d bash`
and i also see the added file `/test`

Note: I tried all kind of character combinations (camel case, lowercase only..) with the same result.

What do i have to change to start my local image directly by name?

Comment: did you try to build the image using "Dummy:latest"? or did you try to run the image using `docker run -it Dummy:1.0 bash`?

Comment: i tried without the tag at all, but latest is not working either. This would be nice though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing the tag in your `run` command.

```
docker run -it Dummy:11.2 bash
```